# CD help and Dead Computer

Tags: 12.04, usb, cd

I am trying to burn 12.04 on a CD. Should be it working or is it not? After reading a couple of other forums that relates to this question, they say to use a 700MB CD which I am but again is not working. Another question is that the reason for this is because I have a School Desktop which I use and the OS seems to have crashed and that OS files seem to be missing so this looks like an option at the moment. So basically, Can't burn it on a CD (says its too small) and trying to rework a partial dead computer...

Comment: Instead of appending `[Solved]` to the title, it would be better if you mark the answer which helped you resolve the problem. To mark the answer as accepted, click on the "tick" besides the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a 4gb usb

Download the iso of the [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=64&distro=desktop&status=zeroc)

Download [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)(If you are using windows to make bootable usb)

Make bootable usb

Use that on system where you want to install the Ubuntu

Done

Comment: The problem is that it is a really old computer and I have already tried booting it

Comment: Hmmm old computer doesn't have an option to boot from usb ? 
if thats the case then you better buy a DVD and burn the ubuntu on it or if you just need any operating system on that system then find a distribution like [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/), it will be burned on your 700mb CD too and you can boot from that

Comment: Don't worry got that sorted and have already put Xubuntu on it just to start. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

12.04.03 is 708MB in size.

It only fits on a 800MB CD, but they are rare (at least in my country).

Your best bet is to [burn it on a DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu) or put the [installer on an USB drive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu), if your PC ist capable of booting from usb.